# IPv4 iptables blocks things, but output policy is ACCEPT, what is the problem with my INPUT DROP chain?

Tags: networking, iptables, ipv4, loopback

This is my IPv4 `iptables` list at this moment:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

When I try to use `apt-get`, it fails to translate the DNS names to IPs.
How can I fix this and make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed allowing the loopback device, which is non-optional:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment loopback -j ACCEPT
```

add this as the very first rule and you're done. I found a good extensive explanation for you as for [what this device represents, etc. on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/247626/436624).

---

Further, I advise optional steps - step 2: allowing ICMP protocol:

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 5/sec --limit-burst 15 -m comment --comment icmp -j ACCEPT
```

---

And finally, I advise optional steps - step 3: restrict your SSH connections to local network only, just make sure to change to your subnet:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment ssh -j ACCEPT
```

---

Side note: After a few hours you should see such DROP numbers when using INPUT DROP rule:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 8354 packets, 732K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     6315  612K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere             /* loopback */
2       13  1072 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/sec burst 15 /* icmp */
3     190K  697M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* traffic */
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:ssh /* ssh */
```